# Datatable serverside show count result of column with spesific values on footer

Tags: datatable, server-side

How to make total row on footer like this with serverside DataTable

```
| Name  | Boy  | Girl |
```


| Boy1  |  -   |      |
| Girl1 |      |  -   |
| Boy2  |  -   |      |
**| Total |  2   |  1   |**

I use this query but the result only show 1 data (it should be 3 data for example)

```
select name, sum(case when sex = "male" then 1 else 0 end) as boy, sum(case when sex = "female" then 1 else 0 end) as girl' from student;
```

Thank you

Comment: Which database are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your database supports `ROLLUP` functionality, then you can try the following:

```
SELECT
    name,
    SUM(CASE WHEN sex = "male"   THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS boy,
    SUM(CASE WHEN sex = "female" THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS girl
FROM student
GROUP BY name
WITH ROLLUP
```

If you database does *not* support `ROLLUP`, then can use a `UNION` to add a record on the bottom for the total:

```
SELECT
    name,
    SUM(CASE WHEN sex = "male"   THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS boy,
    SUM(CASE WHEN sex = "female" THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS girl
FROM student
GROUP BY name
UNION ALL
SELECT
    'total',
    SUM(CASE WHEN sex = "male"   THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
    SUM(CASE WHEN sex = "female" THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
FROM student
ORDER BY
    CASE WHEN name = 'total' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,
    name
```

Comment: Thank you, that is perfect :)